# Extracting Attribute Values of a div in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the, 'project' value  (the url)from the following. Is it possible to do? Any guidance will be highly appreciated.

```
<div class="js-project-group">
<div class="grid-row flex flex-wrap">
<div class="js-react-proj-card grid-col-12 grid-col-6-sm grid-col-4-lg" data-pid="564032676" data-project='{
           "id":564032676,
           "name":"SONOFF NSPanel Smart Scene Wall Switch",
           "urls":{"web":{"project":"https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/sonoffnspanel/sonoff-nspanel-smart-scene-wall-switch"}}}'>

           SOME CONTENT 
</div>
<div>SAME ALIKE DIV AS ABOVE</div>
</div> #closing div of grid-row flex flex-wrap
<div>SAME ALIKE DIV AS THE FIRST</div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**
My try:

```
projectlist = soup.find_all('div', class_='js-project-group')
projectdata =[]
for project in projectlist:
    tag = project.find('div', class_="js-react-proj-card grid-col-12 grid-col-6-sm grid-col-4-lg")
    attribute = tag['data-project']
    projectdata.append(attribute)
```

It just gets only the project data in the first div. What I have done wrong?

**EDIT** Entire HTML structure:

```
<div class="js-project-group" >
  <div class="grid-row flex flex-wrap">
    <div class="js-react-proj-card></div>
    <div class="js-react-proj-card></div>
    <div class="js-react-proj-card></div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-row flex flex-wrap">
    <div class="js-react-proj-card></div>
    <div class="js-react-proj-card></div>
    <div class="js-react-proj-card></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please show the entire HTML structure? Without the content just the structure.

Comment: @Anne can you provide the url you requesting, I guess it is something like [search result](https://www.kickstarter.com/discover/advanced?ref=nav_search&term=smart%20panel) or [category](https://www.kickstarter.com/discover/categories/technology/diy%20electronics) - updated my example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should definitely invest a little more time in your questioning, so that the scenario is comprehensible and reproducible for everyone - next time you will do it better - right? -> Check this [documentation of minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

#### What happens?

You try to scrape all projects but still selected the container. That means for your loop, that it iterates only one time.

#### How to fix?

Select all the projects in the container and iterate:

```
soup.select('div.js-project-group div.js-react-proj-card.grid-col-12.grid-col-6-sm.grid-col-4-lg')
```

To get the url you can `json.loads()` your attribut and navigate to the project url:

`json.loads(attribute)['urls']['web']['project']`

#### Example (based on category [technology / electronic](https://www.kickstarter.com/discover/categories/technology/diy%20electronics))

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://www.kickstarter.com/discover/categories/technology/diy%20electronics"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36'}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,'lxml')



projectdata =[]
for project in soup.select('div.js-project-group div.js-react-proj-card.grid-col-12.grid-col-6-sm.grid-col-4-lg'):
    attribute = project['data-project']
    projectdata.append(json.loads(attribute)['urls']['web']['project'])
projectdata
```

#### Output

```
['https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/albertgajsak/circuitmess-batmobile',
 'https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/udoo/udoo-key-the-4-ai-platform',
 'https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/sonoffnspanel/sonoff-nspanel-smart-scene-wall-switch',
 'https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/olman/smart-trays',
 'https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/sbcshop1/pico-led-cube-on-raspberry-pi-pico',
 'https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/fluffee-anion-brush/fluffee-anion-pet-grooming-brush',
 'https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/172204344/ninja-counter-an-arduino-and-raspberry-pi-programmable-timer',
 'https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/amritsingh/pico-air-monitoring-expansion-measure-pm-level-with-pico',
 'https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/eddietay/retro-dreamer-g4a-cm4-by-my-retro-game-case',
 'https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1405172335/self-powered-rotating-pumpkin-pedestal',
 'https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/udoo/udoo-android-linux-arduino-in-a-tiny-single-board',
 'https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/udoo/udoo-neo-raspberry-pi-arduino-wi-fi-bt-40-sensors']
```